# can't seem to find System.Windows

Tags: c#, reference

I can't seem to find the System.Windows assembly. I tried to add a reference under the tab .NET but it is not there. 
There is a

- system.windows.form
- system.windows.form.datavisualisation
- system.windows.input.Manipulations
- system.windows.Presentation

What i wan to do is play a little with hexcollor converting. Does anyone know what I should add or where I can find the System.windows?

thanks in advance

Comment: Add System.Windows.Forms, that IS the main Windows namespace. Color itself is located in System.Drawing however.

Comment: Have you added the reference? you're probably working on a project that is not a WinForms one.

Answer (score 1):

For System.Windows you need to add reference to WindowsBase.

And try this post if it helps with your hex to color conversion:
[Convert .Net Color Objects to HEX codes and Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982028/convert-net-color-objects-to-hex-codes-and-back)