# Convert color to byte value

Tags: c#, image, hex

In C#, how can I convert a `Color` object into a `byte` value?

For example, the color `#FFF` would be converted to the value `255`.

Comment: Did you not find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/982028/1945651) when you Googled? It's the first match when I search for "convert html color to .net color".

Comment: The below answers suggesting ColorConverter.ConvertFromString() may be preferable though.

Comment: I have a color variable in c# and i want it to be converted to bytes value. and thank you for negative points i wont post more question here.

Comment: What color system are you using where colors are represented by a single 8-bit value? I'm not one of the people who downvoted you BTW.

Comment: If you want the byte values of the colors, you need only access `color.R`, `color.G`, and `color.B`.  This will give you three bytes, though, not just one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the byte values of a .NET `Color` object with:

```
byte red = color.R;
byte green = color.G;
byte blue = color.B;
```

That gives you 3 bytes.  I don't know how you expect to get a single byte value.  Colors are (AFAIK) almost never represented by single bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`ColorTranslator.FromHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx) function:

```
Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFF");
```

Comment: I mean i have Color value, i want it to be converted to Bytes value

Comment: Color a; //------------- It contain #FFF now i want a to bytes value

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your question. You wrote exactly the opposite.

Comment: No, i wrote the same ,... check the caption.
 

How to convert color in c# into bytes value?

Comment: Then I guess you are the only one to understand it because as you can see all answers are showing exactly the contrary. How to get a Color instance from a string.

Comment: this forum is for helping but not take out such mistakes :) isnt it. I usually post after searching alot, i dont post my homeworks here but still alot people give me -ve points which dishearts me not to post on such forums. Any how do u know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ConvertFromString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.convertfromstring.aspx) method from [`ColorConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653060.aspx) class.

> Attempts to convert a string to a Color.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Object
A Color that represents the converted text.
```

---

```
ColorConverter c = new ColorConverter();
Color color = (Color)c.ConvertFromString("#FFF");
Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
string colorcode = "#FFFFFF00";
int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

also see this [How to get Color from Hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net)