# C# Convert Color to argb

Tags: c#, colors, argb

How to  convert Color to argb as array int

pseudo example

```
Color color=nw.GetPixel(i, j);
int[] argbarray = color.toARGBArray();

result:
argbarray[0]=255  (alpha)
argbarray[1]=241  (red)
argbarray[2]=128  (green)
argbarray[3]=69   (blue)
```

Comment: those are already available as properties: `color.A, color.R...`

Comment: it would be better answered than to put a minus

Comment: What is the problem with your current code while doing it?

Comment: if you are talking to me, I didnt "put a minus"  I did answer,,,except for the array part (that is left for the student)

Comment: @Plutonix, I have never found such that you write, and I was looking for a very long and hard

Comment: @Plutonix, While I was writing you've already answered

Comment: Open Object browser; search for color - it will be under System.Drawing.  Examine the properties there; or on MSDN or look at the list that intellisense offers.  You'd have to work hard to miss them

Comment: I searched through Google, he did not give the sense of anything that I needed

Comment: `Color c = Color.Red;`  then type `c.`  Intellisense will open up a list of the props and methods related to Color - *right there at the top* are `A, B` and `G`.  You'd have to work to avoid them

Comment: @Plutonix already realized and wrote

Answer (score 3):

> I searched through Google, he did not give the sense of anything that I needed

I googled `C# color bytes` and this is the first result [Convert color to byte value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601759/convert-color-to-byte-value)

still no sense?

BTW: My way would be:

```
Color color = Color.FromArgb(1,2,3,4);  //alpha,red, green, blue
var argbarray = BitConverter.GetBytes(color.ToArgb())
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray();
```

---

```
argbarray[0]=1  (alpha)
argbarray[1]=2  (red)
argbarray[2]=3  (green)
argbarray[3]=4  (blue)
```

Comment: My queries are different from the above  "I googled C# color bytes and this is the first result Convert color to byte value"

Comment: @user2812337 than explain it. I see no difference. Above code does exactly what you expect from `toARGBArray` in your pseudo code

Comment: now I'll know, and other users will find this answer

Comment: example  https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=Color%20to%20int&gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&hl=ru&q=c%23+Color+to+int

Comment: @user2812337 What should I understand from your comments? *"I am so ignorant that I can even understand a correct answer posted"* ?

Comment: no I meant that my inquiries in Google were incorrect