# How to convert a OLE Color to Hex and back in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net

I need to convert a OLE Color to and from a hex color for the web, kind of like the example here: [Convert .Net Color Objects to HEX codes and Back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982028/convert-net-color-objects-to-hex-codes-and-back)

But the problem is I need to do it in Javascript, so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [JQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) fit the bill?

`var rgba = $.Color("#ff0000").rgba()` gives `[255,0,0,1]`

You can get a single rgb int (ignoring alpha) out of that with:

```
(rgba[0] << 16) + (rgba[1] << 8) + rgba[2]
```

Comment: The main thing is I don't see how to get the hex back to a color int. I think I can make the int to hex work.